# How to use the same child component in blazor many times with different behaviour? / Why does my child component behave like a static one

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have to make a filtering component in order to filter some rows in a blazor table.
I created a filter component and it works fine when i use it only once in my parent component.
If i put a second one then both components have the input and output of the second component. The first one will get overwritten.

It seems like components are static. What i mean by that is that they only exist once in the programm and i can not use more instances of them.

Here is some code:

The component:

```
@typeparam TItem

<ContextMenuTrigger MenuId="MultipleFilter" MouseButtonTrigger="MouseButtonTrigger.Left">
@Icon
</ContextMenuTrigger>

<ContextMenu Id="MultipleFilter">
    <Item CssClass="filter-multi-select-item">
        <div class="filter-multi-select-wrap">
            <span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="" @onchange="selectAll" checked="checkedAll" />
                (Select All)
            </span>
            @foreach(TItem item in DataList ?? Array.Empty<TItem>())
            {
                <span>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" @onchange="@(() => {ChooseUnchooseItem(item);})" checked="@_chosenList.Contains(item)" />
                    @ChildContent(item)
                </span>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="filter-multi-select-footer float-right">
            <input type="button" class="btn-sm btn-outline-primary" value="Ok" @onclick="InvokeOkay" />
            <input type="button" class="btn-sm btn-secondary" value="Cancel" @onclick="InvokeCancel" />
        </div>
    </Item>
</ContextMenu>

[Parameter]
    public MarkupString Icon { get; set; }
    [Parameter]  public IEnumerable<TItem> DataList { get; set; }
    [Parameter]  public List<TItem> DisplayedList { get; set; }
    [Parameter]  public RenderFragment<TItem> ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnOkay { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnCancel { get; set; }

    List<TItem> _chosenList = new();

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        _chosenList = DisplayedList;
        Debug.WriteLine(_chosenList.Count);
    }
....
...
..
```

The Parent:

```
<th style="cursor: pointer; width:10%;">
    <span>
        <FilterComponent 
            Icon="@icon"
            DataList="customerDataList" 
            DisplayedList = "customerDisplayedList"
            Context="customerContext" 
            OnOkay="SubmitFilterComponent" 
            OnCancel="CancelFilterComponent">
                @customerContext.Name
        </FilterComponent>
    </span>
    <span @onclick="sort">
        @_utilities.ShowSortIcon()
        Customer
    </span>
</th>
<th style="cursor: pointer; width:10%;">
    <span>
        <FilterComponent 
            Icon="@icon"
            DataList="serviceDataList" 
            DisplayedList = "serviceDisplayedList"
            Context="serviceContext" 
            OnOkay="SubmitFilterComponent" 
            OnCancel="CancelFilterComponent">
                @serviceContext.Name
        </FilterComponent>
    </span>
    <span @onclick="sort">
        @_utilities.ShowSortIcon()
        Customer
    </span>
</th>
```

I tried using a differnt Context but this did not work.

Is there a possibility to solve my problem this way or should i consider an other way of implementation.

Does this maybe is not a blazor problem but comes from the [ContextMenu](https://github.com/stavroskasidis/BlazorContextMenu)?

Answer (score 1):

Okay i was able to solve my problem myself. I will let this post here in order to help other people which may face the same problem.

My assumption that this was not a blazor problem but a ContextMenu missconfiguration was right.

Following changes solve the problem:

```
<ContextMenuTrigger MenuId="@($"MultipleFilter_{Id}")" ....

<ContextMenu Id="@($"MultipleFilter_{Id}")">


@code {
[Parameter]
public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

I have to use a unique id for each context menu. Then it works.

Comment: Ah, I posted my answer literally few seconds after you posted your own solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because of the use of the same `Id` on both instances of `ContextMenu` component, as you have 2x FilterComponent there.

Generate unique IDs:

```
@typeparam TItem

@code {
    private string _uniqueId;
    private string _contextMenuId;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        _contextMenuId = $"MultipleFilter_{_uniqueId}";
    }
}

<ContextMenuTrigger MenuId="@_contextMenuId" MouseButtonTrigger="MouseButtonTrigger.Left">
    @Icon
</ContextMenuTrigger>

<ContextMenu Id="@_contextMenuId">
    ...
</ContextMenu>
```

There might also be an issue with the _chosenList, you might just init it inside OnParametersSet, but I'm not sure whether that contributes to the problem:

```
@typeparam TItem

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<TItem> DisplayedList { get; set; }
    private List<TItem> _chosenList;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        _chosenList = new List<TItem>(DisplayedList);
        Debug.WriteLine(_chosenList.Count);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey Varin,
you are right. Thank you for your response. I also found this out. Check my answer below.

Comment: @developer1926 Yes, I've seen it, we were writing the posts at the same time. Please select one as an answer and maybe upvote so the people who come here after know that this has been resolved.